# Getting unexpected EOF error on ( dict_data = eval(data) )

Tags: python, eoferror

I'm getting an EOF error in the `dict_data = eval(data)` line while parsing...What can be the reason? How can I save data inside the file in the form of a dictionary and, add data to the dictionary in that file?

```py
class Family:
    Name = 'BORAD FAMILY'
    data = {'sarita':'Engineer','smruti':'CA','kishorbhai':'7 pass','manjuben':'10 pass'}

    def __init__(self,p_name,p_age,p_edu='unknown'):
        self.name = p_name
        self.age = p_age
        self.education = p_edu

    def info(self):
        print('person name is:- ',self.name.capitalize())
        print(self.name, 'age is:- ',self.age)
        print(self.name, 'education is:- ',self.education)

    def profession(self):
        with open('prof.txt','w+') as f1:
            data = f1.read()
            dict_data = eval(data)
            if self.name.lower() in dict_data:
                print(self.name.capitalize(), 'is',dict_data[self.name.lower()])
            else:
                print('data is not available')
                option = input('do you want to add data yes | no').lower()
                def check(option):
                    if option == 'yes':
                        name1 = input('enter the name').lower()
                        profession = input('enter profession').lower()
                        Family.data[name1] = profession
                        f1.writelines(Family.data)
                        print('data saved successfully')
                    elif option == 'no':
                        print('thank you')
                    else:
                        option1 = input('you entered wrong !! enter yes | no')
                        check(option1)
                check(option)


p1 = Family('sarita',25,'BE - ELEC')
p2 = Family('smruti',20,'ca')

# p1.info()
# p2.info()
p1.profession()
p2.profession()
```

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].
 - emphasis on **minimal** : just enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The most important piece of information is what's in `data`. Can you `print(data)` and post it here?

Comment: Can you confirm that the data file is basically equal to the data variable you declared?